# Only one image view shows animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have the following code and I am trying to implement the flip card animation. When I click on second image view it flips and turns abruptly (tough to explain, it just flips rapidly). Also, when I click on the second imageview, animation on first imageview gets started. Could you please suggest me how to fix this? i only want then animation on the card to be started when that particular card is clicked.

```
 package com.example.twocards;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.app.Activity;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
AnimationListener {

       private Animation animation1;
       private Animation animation2;
       private boolean isBackOfCardShowing = true;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.to_middle);
             animation1.setAnimationListener(this);
             animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_middle);
             animation2.setAnimationListener(this);
             findViewById(R.id.imageView2).setOnClickListener(this);
             findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setOnClickListener(this);
       }
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView1) {
              v.setEnabled(false);
              ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).clearAnimation();
              ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setAnimation(animation1);
              ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).startAnimation(animation1);
        }else if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView2) {
            v.setEnabled(false);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).clearAnimation();
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setAnimation(animation1);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).startAnimation(animation1);
        }
           }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
              if (animation==animation1) {
                     if (isBackOfCardShowing) {
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.strategy);
                       } else {
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.memory);
                       }
                       ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).clearAnimation();
         ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setAnimation(animation2);
         ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).startAnimation(animation2);
                 } else {
                        isBackOfCardShowing=!isBackOfCardShowing;
                        findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setEnabled(true);
                 }
        }
        public void onAnimationEnd1(Animation animation) {
              if (animation==animation1) {
                     if (isBackOfCardShowing) {
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageResource(R.drawable.memory);
                       } else {
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageResource(R.drawable.strategy);
                       }
                       ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).clearAnimation();
         ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setAnimation(animation2);
         ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).startAnimation(animation2);
                 } else {
                        isBackOfCardShowing=!isBackOfCardShowing;
                        findViewById(R.id.imageView2).setEnabled(true);
                 }
        }




        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onClick1` is not the correct signature unless you set it on the xml with the `android:onClick` property. If the latter is the case, then you have to remove, one between

```
findViewById(R.id.imageView2).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setOnClickListener(this);
```

If it is not the case, then only `onClick(View view)` is called, and you have to distinguish on which view you clicked. One way to do this is to compare the id of the view provide as parameter:

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
         if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView1) {
          v.setEnabled(false);
          ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).clearAnimation();
          ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setAnimation(animation1);
          ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).startAnimation(animation1);
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView2) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Blackbelt. Animation works for second image view as well but  I have another problem now. When i click on second image the animation for first image also gets started. Moreover, animation for second image view only works once. For the first image view everything works fine. Kindly, suggest what should I do.